# How to differ awk $1 argument from bash arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm writing a bash script and to it I pass a few filter arguments.

In it, in a simpler version, I have the following line: `echo 12345 | awk '$1 >= $5'`

However, awk's $1 gets confused with bash's first argument (also $1), which is a totally different value apart from the awk filter.

$5 is an actual bash argument I'm comparing it against.

How do I manage to get awk's first argument and bash's fifth argument in the line mentioned above?

How can I test what awk is actually reading from parameters?

Comment: Use `awk -v arg5="$5" '$1 > arg5'`

Comment: There's probably a much more meaningful name for that value than `arg5` and that would tightly and unnecessarily couple the awk script to the shell script.

Comment: You could do a `awk '$1 >= '"$5"`, but the approach suggested by anubhava is IMO more elegant.

Comment: @user1934428 that could produce cryptic failures depending on the value of `$5` so it's not a great thing to suggest, especially to newcomers who won't know about the issues around it and probably like it for it's brevity.